# Alternative to Jquery UI dialog or other way to use it

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, jquery-ui-dialog

I am building a Chrome extension that encrypts and decrypts emails for Gmail users. I am using Jquery dialog UI to ask the user to enter a password and also to display in clear decrypted emails. The dialog UI has to show up on Gmail pages. So I am injecting the css, scripts on the Gmail page, etc .. and everything works perfectly fine.

However, what's worrying me is the way dialog UI works. Indeed, the body of dialog must be inserted in a div tag which is injected in the web page and then called by dialog ui. That means I have to inject the input tag for password and decrypted messages in the Gmail page before calling dialog ui. So eventually, Gmail can detect it and gets access to this data. So I'd like to find another way to display this information if it's possible.

I tried to use the background.html page, injecting div tag and body in it and then call dialog ui on it, but it looks like it's not possible.

Could anyone suggest another idea ? Maybe other stuff like dialog Ui exists and doesn't require to inject the body of the dialog in the web page in order to diplsay a pop-u^p with buttons ? Or maybe there is another way to use dialog ui ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found how to deal with that. Instead of calling the dialog ui on a div of the gmail page, I just discovered that we can call the dialog ui directly like that : `$(<div></div>).dialog({...});`, so it's not necessary to inject it in the web page.

Comment: That probably injects it into DOM anyway though.

Comment: Really ? I looked at the devtools to see elements and it doesn't show up. Any idea how to better check that ?

Comment: Interesting: maybe I am incorrect with regards to content scripts. Normally you can not have stuff shown on a page without it being in DOM one way or another. But you shouldn't trust me -- just use "Inspect element" on any part of the dialog, and check its parent elements -- I am curious if it works in some other way.

Comment: When you click the option that triggers the dialog, build the div tags on the fly and afterwards invoke the dialog method over it.